# Why does an ASP.Net Web Forms control have to call its own DataBind to pick up bindings defined in its parent's markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms, page-lifecycle

Briefly, I'm working on an app that uses ASP.Net Web Forms.

It has an aspx page that includes a data binding expression to bind one of the page's public properties to a property on a custom control. The actual page is quite complicated, but I was able to duplicate the behavior using a super simple example.

Page.aspx:

```
<uc:CustomControl runat="server" Text='<%# Text %>' />
```

In the OnInit override of the page, it calls the page's DataBind method.

Page.aspx.cs:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
  DataBind();
  base.OnInit(e);
}
```

The problem is that the Text property of the custom child control remains null until that control calls base.DataBind().

UserControl.ascx.cs:

```
public string Text { get; set; }

public override void DataBind()
{
  // Text is null at this point
  base.Databind();
  // Text is populated at this point
}
```

But the data binding expression that binds that text property to the child control's Text property is in the **parent's** markup. Why on earth does the child control's DataBind method have to be called before the value is assigned?

This is dreadfully inconvenient, because it doesn't let you pass data down from the page to an arbitrary depth during data binding. To get access to the data bound value from the parent's markup, the page's child control has to call base.DataBind, but that causes its child controls to get data bound even though it hasn't had time to populate data on those children.

How is data supposed to flow from parent to child during data binding if the data is bound in reverse order? What am I missing?

Comment: I haven't looked into it extensively but note that 'Init' only fires once, not on postbacks. Not sure if that's relevant. Perhaps look into the `InitComplete` event (?). https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Init fires on every request.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a good answer to this question, but I found a solution to my problem by looking at the reference source. There is another virtual method you can override called `DataBindChildren`. It is called after the parent's data binding expressions have been evaluated and bound to the control, so any data you wish to pass down to the children before they are bound can be passed down at that point.